# How to Set mouse cursor position to a specified point on screen in C#?

Tags: c#, automation, mouse, click

How to Set mouse cursor position to a specified point on screen in C#?

am i must hacke the motherboard buffer that receive the mouse and keyboard coordinates and presses ???

is there another one to do clicks or i am imagine ???

Comment: The question that jumps immediately to mind is 'why'?

Comment: to do something in my head. why?

Comment: @MatthewScharley I came here for "automatization"..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Get and set mouse position in Windows 10:**

Much simpler in c# .NET Framework 4.0 using Cursor.Position Property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?view=netcore-3.1

```
    public static void ClickSomePoint()
    {

        // get mouse position
        System.Drawing.Point screenPos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;

        // create X,Y point (0,0) explicitly with System.Drawing 
        System.Drawing.Point leftTop = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);

        // set mouse position
        Cursor.Position = leftTop; 
        Console.WriteLine(screenPos);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

The following will set the mouse position and perform a click:

```
public static void ClickSomePoint() {
    // Set the cursor position
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(20, 35);

    DoClickMouse(0x2); // Left mouse button down
    DoClickMouse(0x4); // Left mouse button up
}   

static void DoClickMouse(int mouseButton) {
    var input = new INPUT() {
        dwType = 0, // Mouse input
        mi = new MOUSEINPUT() { dwFlags = mouseButton }
    };

    if (SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input)) == 0) { 
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MOUSEINPUT {
    int dx;
    int dy;
    int mouseData;
    public int dwFlags;
    int time;
    IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}   
struct INPUT {
    public uint dwType;
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
}   
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint SendInput(uint cInputs, INPUT input, int size);
```

Just keep in mind that this could be ***extremely*** annoying for a user.

:)

---

If you want to click a button on your form you can use the [`'PerformClick()'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(VS.80).aspx) method.

Comment: but if i want to click anything in the screen is there something for that or my imagination will end here ?

Comment: the Exception in the if scope in every time happen. what i could do ?

Comment: Keep in mind that the second parameter of `SendInput` should be `ref`, otherwise the signatures won't match and you'll get a PInvoke exception!

Comment: I guess that won't work on any systems except MS Widows, right?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to position the mouse:

Left zero for left position and zero right for top position (you can change it to any number you want)(to use this code you need to use `using System.Drawing`
and `using System.Windows.Forms` namespace)

`Cursor.Position = new Point(0,0);`