# How to programmatically make a click happen at the co-ordinates the cursor is pointing to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent, emgucv

I am wondering if there is anyway to trigger a click/double click event at the place where the cursor is hovering?

I am using c# and emgu CV for my application.

Comment: Nope. Just a double click on the user's computer!

Comment: `Click()` does work, doesn't it?

Comment: The answer to this question seems to do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392199/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-position-to-a-specified-point-on-screen-in-c

Comment: @user1190826 I have changed the tags to hopefully get more Winforms experts to answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Microsoft Test API](http://testapi.codeplex.com/) for automating mouse pointer positions and clicks in my application. The class you're looking for in the Test API is `Microsoft.Test.Input.Mouse`.