# Moving the mouse according to the given coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent, mouse

what I want is, after recording the mouse movement and saving the coordinates/ indexes/ position, I will have to load the mouse coordinates and make the mouse move according to the loaded coordinates 
i don't have code to show you because am stuck at this point

```
     ' private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter writer;
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            string[] cvsArray = new string[10000];
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.All)|*.All|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                writer = File.CreateText(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                // if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                //{
                for (int i = 0; i < cvsArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    string text = richTextBox1.Text;
                    writer.WriteLine(text);
                }
                // Code to write the stream goes here.
                writer.Close();
                //}
            }
        }
 private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader reader;
            string Line;
            string[] cvsArray;
            string position;

            //set the filter to dialog control
            openFileDialog1.Filter = FILTER;
            //check if the user selected the right file
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //open the selected file
                reader = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //Read the entireline form the file
                Line = reader.ReadLine();
                //read while it is still not the end of the file 
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    Line = reader.ReadLine();
                    //Splite the line using array
                    cvsArray = Line.Split(':');

                    position = cvsArray[0];
                    //position = cvsArray[1];
                    listBox1.Items.Add(position);
                }
            }
        }'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set mouse cursor position to a specified point on screen in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392199/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-position-to-a-specified-point-on-screen-in-c)

Comment: note that you should also save delta time between movements, so when you will move cursor, you should make delays equals to these deltas

Comment: aah, I see, I'll keep that in my mind. Thank you @SamSch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and rather dirty solution:

Let's start with a few varibles:

```
 List<Point> points = null;
 Timer tt = null;
 int index = 0;
```

Now a button to start the recoding; it initializes a `List<Point>` to collect the positions and creates and starts a `Timer` along with `lambda` code to do the recoding in the `Timer.Tick` event:

```
private void btn_Record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    points = new List<Point>();
    index = 0;
    tt = new Timer()
    { Interval = 50, Enabled = true };
    tt.Tick += (ss, ee) => 
    {
        if (!points.Any() || points.Last() != Control.MousePosition) 
           points.Add(Control.MousePosition); 
    };
}
```

Next a button to stop recording:

```
private void btn_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tt!=null) tt.Stop();
}
```

Finally the replay button; it uses an index to loop over the the points collection in a new `Timer.Tick` code but using the same timer:

```
private void btn_Replay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    index = 0;
    tt = new Timer() { Interval = 50, Enabled = true };
    tt.Tick += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (index < points.Count)
          { System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position =  points[index++]; }
        else tt.Stop();
}
```

A few notes:

- As asked in the question this will record and reply the Mmouse coodinates. It will do so in fixed intervals, so playback will look very similar to the original movements; in fact it is so hard to tell apart that I added a slowmo button with a longer interval to demonstrate.. (But the gif got too large)
- The code will record the mouse positions in screen coordinates and should capture them wherever it goes, not only inside your application. See how VS is activating the code loupe!
- It will not record any other mouse events, like up, down, click, doubleclick or wheel. For those you would need a global mouse hook for capturing and some external calls for replaying.
- For including other mouse events you would also need a different and extended data structure; and you would also have to go from a timer-driven model to a mouse event driven one.
- The example uses buttons to start  and stop. Of course the movenments to and from those buttons get included in the recorded list of positions. Instead one could use a timed start, which would start recording after a few seconds and stop recording after a few seconds of inactivity..

There are various ways you can save and load the points; the simplest one is to serialize to xml; using a `string path = @"..."` it could look as simple as  this:

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (points == null) points = new List<Point>();
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer((points).GetType());
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        points =  (List<Point>)xs.Deserialize(tr);
        tr.Close();
    }
}

private void btn_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer((points).GetType());
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        xs.Serialize(tw, points);
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Other ways would be using a binary formatter or a custom conversion routine. Xml is relatively stable.

Here is a short clip:

[image]

Comment: My program does record and saves the indexes, which is what I want so far, but the thing I am working on is making the mouse read the loaded indexes and move according to it. like after I load the indexes i would press play and the mose will move

Comment: That is __exactly__ what the Replay button does. Hard to discern the real and the replayed movement, which only goes to show that it works rather nicely..

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly fine. But what if I have a list of indexes and I want to make the mouse move according to these indexes? or is it better to save the recorded move as a video?  @TaW

Comment: What are those 'indexes'? Where do they come from? And: What is the purpose?

Comment: I have a list that shows me the indexes of the mouse while am moving it. Then I have a save button that allows me to save the what is on the list, and that works. I can save the indexes/ mouse position in the file. Now I have another button that allows to load/ open the file which has the indexes/ mouse position, which is working. (I have a play button that replays the recording) Now after I load I want to press on the play button and that will check if the list !null, then will read the list and make the mouse move according to those positions in the file. (Does it make sense!)  @Taw

Comment: The purpose is to save the recording of the mouse, right now I can only record and replay, but what I also want is to record

Comment: Huh? Please explain this: you can record&replay but not record?? Sounds strange. Do you mean record and store the data? Also: What are the 'idexes' you record? Show the data structure!

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, So I have a button to record and replay just like what you have. I have a listBox1 that is showing me a mouse position and another empty listBox2. I have a button that saves mouse positions from listBox1 in a file. Another button opens a file what has mouse positions and load the positions in listBox2. The data that is showing in listBox2 is a string and not doing anything. So, how can I make the mouse moves when I open a file and load the data? Or is there another way to save the recording?

Comment: Well, there are many way to skin a cat. You can save as a list of strings or serialize to xml. When deserializing you get the original List<Point> back. When reading back a text file you will ahve to convert it line by line. If you want to move the mouse to a position in the listbox you can code the SelectionChanged event. Then covert the string to a Point and move the cursor. If you want I can add code for a save and load button..

Comment: I have written the code for both saving and loading but as a string, but how should I convert by reading line by line?

Comment: Probably by looking into the functions Split and Convert ! But without seeing either code nor data all I can do is guess. - As I wrote, Serializing the data is pretty simple. As is writing&reading numbers

Comment: If I post the code that I have done, would you give me an idea of how should I do it? @TaW

Comment: Sure, edit the question and do include a few lines of the text xyou write. Also decide if you want/need text or can go for xml or even binary..

Comment: I have edited, and If you recommend XML I would like to go for it.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a few notes and a save/load example.

Comment: that was really helpful, thank you very much for helping me out, and sorry for taking too long to replay