# how move cursor inside on coordinates of panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a problem with this code, im triying to move the cursor with coordinates only inside on my panel called resolution(my panel size is 640x480). But when press the button to move the cursor, the cursor leave and stay in upper left corner on my screen, how i can change that?

I read about that and i can use the `poinToScreen` or `poinToClient` to do what i want but not work the cursor leave anyway

the code take coordinates from text files, so i give coordinates to test.

- Coordinates X

```
357                                 
336
338
343
357
263
257
246
276
```

- Coordinates Y

```
124
133
131
127
107
76
-88
-90
-105
```

- Code:

```cs
public void cursor_track_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           List<string> linesX = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coord\CoordinatesX.txt").ToList();
           List<string> linesY = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coord\CoordinatesY.txt").ToList();
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
            for(int i = 0; i< linesX.Count; i++)
            {
                Point p = new Point(int.Parse(linesX[i]), int.Parse(linesY[i]));
                points.Add(p);
            }
            foreach (var point in points) {

                resolution.PointToScreen(Cursor.Position = new Point(point.X, point.Y));

            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

- Added a timer to see the animation
- Added Line code answer by LarsTech

```cs
        Timer tt = null;
        int index = 0;
       public void cursor_track_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<string> linesX = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coord\CoordinateX.txt").ToList();
            List<string> linesY = File.ReadLines(@"C:\EyeMatris\Coord\CoordinateY.txt").ToList();
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
            index = 0;
            tt = new Timer()
            { Interval = 500, Enabled = true };
            tt.Tick += (ss, ee) =>
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < linesX.Count; i++)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(int.Parse(linesX[i]), int.Parse(linesY[i]));
                    points.Add(p);
                }
                foreach (var point in points)
                {
                    //Cursor.Position = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
                    Cursor.Position = resolution.PointToScreen(point);
                    tt.Stop();

                }
            };

        }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also: Why are you moving the cursor in a for loop? There won't be any time to show the result except for the last one. - Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015111/moving-the-mouse-according-to-the-given-coordinates/50018092?r=SearchResults&s=1|20.8974#50018092) is of interest?

Comment: It's winform, the for loop its because im saving coordinates from Eye Tracker to move the cursor or you talk about the cursor move so fast in the for?

Comment: PointToScreen is a function returning a Point.  It's not a method.

Comment: If the loop is supposed to show anything it will not work because a) it has no time to do so and b) you throw away the result of PointToScreen .

Comment: PointToClient have the same function? i read this so im confused [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f2f26a9e-f343-49c3-b1be-6641560202b5/difference-between-pointtoscreen-and-pointtoclient?forum=winformsdesigner)

Comment: My principal panel have 10x10 panels with event mouse enter. My panels change the background color if cursor touch the panel, that is why i need the cursor only move inside on my panel "resolution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PointToXXX functions returns a translated point.  It doesn't set the Cursor position.  Try it like this:

```
Cursor.Position = resolution.PointToScreen(point);
```

You probably have to use a timer to make an animation work.

---

Update from your code, your Tick code should look something like this:

```
tt.Tick += (ss, ee) => {
  if (index > linesX.Count - 1) {
    tt.Stop();
  } else {
    Point p = new Point(int.Parse(linesX[index]), int.Parse(linesY[index]));
    Cursor.Position = resolution.PointToScreen(p);
  }
  index++;
}
```

It would be better to load and convert your file coordinates into a point list before doing any other work.  Some of your coordinates are in the negative, so they might appear off-screen.  Your button should be disabled while the timer is running so the user can't click on it again while it's animating.

Comment: Thank you!!, i will try that

Comment: Hello, i used your code but my cursor still leave my panel

Comment: @JavierAceves Unless you show me your updated code, I don't know what you are looking at.  Update your question with the edit link underneath it.

Comment: @JavierAceves Updated post.

Comment: Thanks, that work! but i cannot convert the negative coordinate, because is data is from eye tracker, that is why only need the cursor stay on my panel "resolution". Your answer work very good only i need test more the coordinates.